# FreeTDS returns strings with null character

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I'm using `freetds + unixODBC + php pdo_odbc` to access `MSSQL Server 2012`

```
+ CentOS 7 x86_64
+ freetds version 0.95.19
+ unixODBC version 2.3.4
+ php version 5.6.14
```

When retreiving results from SQL Server in UTF-8 I get NULL characters `(\u0000 in JSON)` in long strings, which, when htmlencoded by JavaScript becomes "�".
The only thing I've found in the internet is [this post in FreeTDS mailing list](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2013q4/028623.html).

By the way, [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) works fine in this case, but has some other issues I could not solve.

**UPD:** Configs

`/etc/freetds.conf`

```
[global]
  text size = 2147483647
[ibmMSSQL]
  host = ibm.sevkav.local
  port = 49927
  tds version = 7.3
  client charset = UTF-8
```

`/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

[ibmMSSQL]
Description = MSSQL Server
Trace = No
Servername = ibmMSSQL
Database = MRS

[ibmMSSQLnative]
Driver = SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Description = Test MS Driver
Trace = no
Server = ibm.sevkav.local,49927\EAIS_MIRROR
Database = MRS

[Default]
Driver = FreeTDS
```

`/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[ODBC]
#DEBUG=1
#TraceFile=/tmp/sqltrace.log
#Trace=Yes

[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[FreeTDS]
Description=ODBC for FreeTDS
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
FileUsage=1
client charset = utf-8

[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
Driver=/usr/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: So first, I don't believe you can use "client charset" in `odbcinst.ini` - it is probably just being ignored. Can you try adding `Charset=UTF-8` to your DSN definition in odbc.ini?

Comment: Yes, you're right, "client charset" does not affect it at all, changed it to `Charset=UTF-8` and NULL char is still there. I have to mention that I've compilled unixODBC with `./configure --enable-gui=no --enable-drivers=no --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --sysconfigdir=/etc` for native driver from MS.